# How to install a specific version of rebar?

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, rebar

I'm trying to install rebar 2.6.4 using apt-get. When I run

```
sudo apt-get install rebar
rebar -V
```

It shows version

```
rebar 2.0.0 R16B01 20131022_120229 No VCS info available.
```

Is there a way to install version 2.6.4 using apt-get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work.

I cloned rebar from github.com/rebar/rebar, checkedout branch 2.6.4, built the rebar, and coppied the resulting rebar script into /usr/bin directory. Now my rebar works fine and rebar -V displays

```
rebar 2.6.4 R16B03 20161121_162253 git 2.6.4
```

Answer (score 1):

try to run an apt-get update and then try to autocomplete before installing to see what is available for installation. If that doesn't work you can always install the package you want from the official website directly

Comment: Autocompleting only shows the original rebar package, no other versions. I got rebar 2.6.4 build from its git repository but I can't use it as bash command(which is what I'm trying to do)

Comment: you have to either add it to your $PATH or just type in the path every time you use it

Answer (score -1):

Usage latest version of Ubuntu (zesty)
http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/rebar

Or download deb package manual:

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rebar/rebar_2.6.4-2_amd64.deb
and install:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./rebar_2.6.4-2_amd64.deb
```